# How to send feed back information to server via my application?

Tags: windows, http, windows-phone-7

In my application feedback form will be used .i have to send feedback information to server.please help me how to send information to server in windows phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the EmailTask:

```
var emailTask = new EmailComposeTask
{
    To = "feedback@mycompany.com",
    Subject = subjectTextBox.Text,
    Body = String.Format("Dear {0},/nPlease let {1}" + 
           " know that I would like to {2}.\nThis " + 
           "has been bothering me for {3} days now. " + 
           "I hope you can help me out. Kindest " + 
           "regards,\n{4}\n", toTextBox.Text, 
           nameTextBox.Text, activityTextBox.Text, 
           daysTextBox.Text, senderTextBox.Text)
};

emailTask.Show();
```

or you could publish a web service or you could have a web page that you point the WebBrowser control to.

It all depends on the way you want to receive the feedback and (perhaps) continue the conversation.

Comment: but in my application name,mail-id,subject,feedback like 8 text box will be used.how to send that information to server?

Comment: I added to my answer. Does it that help?

Comment: thank you very much this will be helped a lot.sorry I'm new to windows phone.

Comment: Don't be sorry about that, that is what this site is here for. Glad to help.