# Send feedback information to server?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

In my application I have used

```
 name, mail-id, subject ,feedback
```

like 8 text boxes.

How to send that information to server? The server link is like: `http://android.de/formular/formular_senden.php`

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Comment: Also, don't [repost your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188251/how-to-send-feed-back-information-to-server-via-my-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about Windows phone Application。 there are have two way send User Feedback.
you can use WebRequest to PostData .
or use emailTask send email with Text Content，。

Comment: I found exactly what I was looking for: http://www.dot4pro.com/posting-data-to-the-web-from-windows-phone-7.html